# Calculate market cap and number of holders using web3?

Tags: ethereum, web3js

I'm new into this wold of cryptocurrencies (technically). I'm learning a little by using web3 library on node.js in order to get some information about BSC tokens (Binance Smart Chain).

I figured out how to get the price from a token using web3 after a couple days of investigation. What I'd like to do now, is to get the market capitalization and number of holders for specific token.

Is there any way I can get that information by using web3 on my node.js backend? Or is there any free API with examples where I can get this information?

I know there are some API's that get this information, for example, **BSCScan**. The problem is it requires you to use an API Key Pro, and I applied / asked information for it some days ago but no replies yet.

An example of the token I'd like to get the information is this: https://bscscan.com/token/0x5e90253fbae4dab78aa351f4e6fed08a64ab5590

Also tried **BitQuery** to do this but with no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Here is an example of how to build a database of token holders: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/92571/620

Comment: Thanks Mikko. I'll check it! any ideas about getting market cap too?

Comment: Market cap is `totalSupply() * price of exchange you choose`

Comment: Sorry. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Suppose given example: https://bscscan.com/token/0x5e90253fbae4dab78aa351f4e6fed08a64ab5590

The total supply for that token is 1,000,000,000,000,000
The actual price for that token is 0.000000526819

So once I multiply those numbers i'm getting ≈ 500 million market cap, but in websites for reference (where data seems to be correctly) the market cap is  ≈ 320 million (check here: https://poocoin.app/tokens/0x5e90253fbae4dab78aa351f4e6fed08a64ab5590)

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: They use either different price or supply for the calculations.

Comment: @emmab you are missing the burnt tokens. Burnt tokens are calculated towards the price.